# Angular 2 / Typescript -- what's the difference between my IDE and tutorial screenshot?

Tags: angularjs, templates, typescript, routes, sublimetext

I was checking out the [Scotch.io tutorial on routing](https://scotch.io/tutorials/routing-angular-2-single-page-apps-with-the-component-router) and noticed that when I added the following snippet to my own project, the template string in between the 'grave accent' was all yellow...what is the significance of this?

First pic is from tutorial, second is from Sublime Text.

[image: tutorial]

[image: Sublime]

Comment: Are you using the [TypeScript plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TypeScript) for Sublime?

Comment: I added the TypeScript plugin to see if it made a difference, which it didn't. It also created a .js duplicate of all .ts files which I found somewhat irritating.

Answer (score 1):

### There is no real significance

There isn't really any significance to this. It just means that the IDE used in the tutorial understands what is going on in that code. As in, it sees that it is HTML, which is part of a component. It seems that your IDE is just saying "this is a string".

But that is just your IDE. Your code will work just fine, you could actually just code everything in `Notepad`if you were so inclined, which would understand *nothing* of the meaning behind the code.